# Mathjax3 overflows bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, mathjax

I am using MathJax3 with Bootstrap4. I know that automatic line breaking hasn't been ported to MathJax3 yet.

In the following code, I have 3 columns: a left spacing column, a main column with the latex equation, and a right column with some text.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- MathJax3 -->
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
    <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
        tags: 'ams'
      }
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            A very long mathjax equation:
            
            \begin{equation}
                y = 2^x + 6x + 9x + 2^x + 6x + 9x + 2^x + 6x + 9x 
                2^x + 6x + 9x + 2^x + 6x + 9x + 2^x + 6x + 9x + 
                2^x + 6x + 9x + 2^x + 6x + 9x + 2^x + 6x + 9x + 
            \end{equation}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            Some other text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is the image below. You can see how the mathjax equation overflows the central column. What I would like to is that if this happens, the right column is moved below the equation, the same that would happen if the screen was of size < `sm`. Is there a way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure what you meant in the last sentence of your question, but does my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve what you desire, replace `col-sm-6` class from the MathJax column with `col`

See: https://jsfiddle.net/koder613/hsg5k1ry/3/

As an aside, a quick solution to stop the MathJax overflowing would be to set `overflow-x: scroll` in your `css` for that column with MathJax in.

Comment: Using col instead of col-sm-6 fixes the problem if the equation is too long, but makes the right column go below also if the equation is short. But I like the overflow-x solution! Is there a way to use the overflow only on big screens -md and above-, and the other one in sm and below?

Comment: @FedericoTaschin Does this link work better: https://www.codeply.com/p/Wim1A8XWny